# Is there a way to "undo" in Windows Phone?

Tags: functionality

In the old days (Pocket PC, Windows Mobile) it was possible to use CTRL+Z on the soft keyboard just like on a full keyboard.

Now in Windows Phone, with no CTRL key, is there a way to "undo" a typing mistake? For full blown Office documents in Word or OneNote it's all too easy to overwrite quite a large chunk of text by mistake.

What can I do at that "aaaaaaaargh" moment?

Comment: I retagged this with Mango, as I think it's a deficiency that is likely to be fixed for Apollo.

Comment: @paradroid you can't know that for sure. The tag is to be used when the question is specific to Mango. Currently, is it not and thus should not have the tag.

Comment: Since this is not a feature that is currently available, you may request for this feature using the link: https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just finished speaking with the Windows Phone support team to help get your question answered.

There is no "undo" operation in Word Mobile, the documentation is wrong in the product guide and is probably old. Here is the link to the current documentation for Office Mobile. http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-US/howto/wp7/office/use-office-word-mobile.aspx

As far as a workaround goes, there isn't much you can do other than saving frequently. You can hit back, then select "do not save" to make sure your mistake doesnt overwrite your work.

Comment: Thanks for following up with support and for the link. Wish there was an "undo" though!

Comment: Not that I care much, but how's this different from my answer? :)

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo i accepted this one just because Lance says he's spoken to support and because he links to a document which updated and added info to the other (now deleted) answer

Comment: If you'd like to see the conversation with Windows Phone Support, look me up on twitter (@lancewmccarthy). I started the conversation with them at 11:15 (EST) 5/10/2012, I dont know how long twitter holds on to tweets but it should be there for a little while.

Answer (score 9):

From my experience with Windows Phone Office, Undo and Redo are available only in Excel.

If you want to ensure that no big chunks of data will be lost during a Word or OneNote document editing, save it as often as you can. Whenever you have that "aaaaaaaargh" moment, back out without saving the document and open it again. This is the only method I'm aware of.

You can upvote a [related feature suggestion](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2287334-add-undo-to-one-note-office-apps) at [windowsphone.uservoice.com](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the old Ctrl + Z if you got a keyboard attached to your phone.
I don't know why there is the substructure for that but the functionality couldn't be reached through the device itself.